# Using Mainframe Datasets in Python 3.6 within Anaconda Spyder

Tags: python-3.6, mainframe

I am trying to read and write the Mainframe Datasets data in Python3.6. I am using Anaconda's Spyder(version 3.2.4). I am using Zosftplib inorder to import mainframe features. Below is the code snippet:
    import zosftplib
    Myzftp = zosftplib.Zftp("ip address-mainframe","username","password")
    mf_file = open("mainframe ps file-name", 'r+')
    ffa = mf_file.read(16);
    print ("Read record is :", ffa)
    mf_file.close()

Mainframe PS-file name contains 1 record with data-0010021023457893.But the output I am getting is spaces in Spyder kernel.I also tried using ftplib but it didn't worked there too.I believe there's conversion required as its not a text file which I am reading.Does anyone has any suggestion on this.Please reply.Thanks

Thru FTPLIB and Zosftplib import

```
import zosftplib
Myzftp = zosftplib.Zftp("ip address-mainframe","username","password")
mf_file = open("mainframe ps file-name", 'r+')
ffa = mf_file.read(16);
print ("Read record is :", ffa)
mf_file.close()
```

Expected result should be 0010021023457893 after file read and print.

Comment: Mainframe FTP can be tricky as there are two different file systems, traditional mainframe datasets and UNIX hierarchical file systems. I am not  a Python person, but it could be that the file you are trying to access is the wrong type for where you start.

You can change between them with the "cd" command. cd '' takes you out of UNIX mode and in to MVS mode. cd /u/myUser for example takes you into UNIX mode.

If you connect to the mainframe using a command line, where do you start?

Comment: Not specific to your problem, but [this](https://github.com/cschneid-the-elder/rants/blob/master/advice-reading-mainframe-data.md) may be useful.  More specific to your problem - are there errors reported in the mainframe logs?  Access errors, perhaps?

Comment: Are you trying to access an MVS file (you mention PS-file which I think means Physical Sequential and thus an MVS file object).

Answer (score 2):

The zosftplib package will provide you ftp access to your dataset on z/OS, meaning you can download it, but you have to open it locally.  Also, you need to be aware of the encoding differences between your local machine and the z/OS environment, so you should specify the sbdataconn() argument to provide codepage translation.  I was able to do what you want with code like this:

```
import zosftplib

Myzftp = zosftplib.Zftp('mainframe_ip', 
                        'mainframe_userid', 
                        'mainframe_password',
                        timeout=500.0, 
                        sbdataconn='(ibm-1147,iso8859-1)')
Myzftp.download_text('mainframe_dataset_name', '/tmp/local_filename.txt')

mf_file = open('/tmp/local_filename.txt', 'r+')
ffa = mf_file.read(16);
print ("Read record is :", ffa)
mf_file.close()
```

Comment: Sorry for Late Reply.The above suggested code worked for me.Thank you!

Comment: @Mohit Good to hear you solved your problem! Can you mark the answer as correct? This will help others who are having the same problem find this answer. Thanks 